# Specifying colors in the columns based on the column values in a table

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using below code to specify the colors for different type of ranges.

```
<td align="center" style="background-color: 
                      {!IF(AND({!profileList.Quantity} >= 0, {!profileList.Quantity} <= 10), '#00FF00', 
                        IF(AND({!profileList.Quantity} >= 11, {!profileList.Quantity} <= 14), '#FFFF00', 
                        IF(AND({!profileList.Quantity} >= 15, {!profileList.Quantity} <= 19), '#FFA500', '#FF0000')))}">{!profileList.Quantity}</td>
```

{!profileList.Quantity} is the number which having range from 0 t0 more than 20.

When I am saving the component it give me the below error.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An attribute in lightning must be *completely* a merge field, or not at all. You can't mix them like this. This syntax wouldn't even be valid in Visualforce, much less Lightning.

In addition, you cannot put a literal `<` or `>` in your expression, so you need to either escape it, or use the appropriate operator.

## Escaping

```
style="{!'background-color: #' + 
  if(profileList.Quantity &lt;= 10, '00FF00',
  if(profileList.Quantity &lt;= 14, 'FFFF00',
  if(profileList.Quantity &lt;= 19, 'FFA500', 'FF0000')))}"
```

## Operators

```
style="{!'background-color: #' + 
  if(profileList.Quantity le 10, '00FF00',
  if(profileList.Quantity le 14, 'FFFF00',
  if(profileList.Quantity le 19, 'FFA500', 'FF0000')))}"
```

You can read more in the [Expressions Function Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_functions.htm) for an explanation on how `le` and the related operators work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly I noticed that you can't combine the  `{!` delimiter for every expression. It just a syntax used to begin an expression.

**Eg:**

<s>`{!IF(AND({!profileList.Quantity} >= 0, {!profileList.Quantity} <= 10), '#00FF00'`</s>

**the correct way to do is**

`{!if(and(greaterthanorequal(profileList.Quantity ,0), lessthanorequal(profileList.Quantity ,10)), '#00FF00'), '#00FF00' }`

2. Lightning is case sensitive Expression functions are not be capitalize.<s>`{!IF(AND`</s> instead  `{!if(and`

3.You can also  use `<= or >=` otheralternative is `&lt;=` or `(greaterthanorequal(v.contdition ,2),2)`

Here is the example code for your refernece

**Example**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="contdition" type="integer" default="1" />


    <td align="center" style="{! 'background-color:' + 
                              if(and(v.contdition >= 1 ,1), '#00FF00',
                              if(and(greaterthanorequal(v.contdition ,2),2),'#FFFF00',
                              if(and(v.contdition &lt;= 3,3),'#FFA500','#FF0000')
                              ))}">test</td>
</aura:application>
```